# Python Selenium Can't locate google sheet element

Tags: python, selenium, google-sheets

I have tried all ways possible to locate the bellow import file window elements from google sheets and yet haven't locate it. Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

import time

import pynput

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()

import os
import logging
import glob

#save chrome user data to chromedriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("") #Path to your chrome profile

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)

#open the google sheet in chrome
driver.get("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/")
wait3 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "docs-file-menu")))

#click on file menue
wait3 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "docs-file-menu")))
driver.find_element_by_id("docs-file-menu").click()

#click on import
wait3 = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, ":4q")))
driver.find_element_by_id(":4q").click()
```

[Google Sheet import Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJkiw.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to get help

Comment: Please share whatever code you have written till now. So that we can investigate and suggest a correction.

Comment: tried to use all options (IDs, Classes, Xpaths, Css selector) for all elements in the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Element which you are looking for is in the `iframe`.

First, you have to switch to that `iframe` and then start searching for your element.